# Passing parameters into WebBrowserDocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

Let's say I have a function as such:

```
public TestStuff() {

    string testing = "test";
    webBrowser2.Navigate("http://google.com");
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;

}

public WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs Url) {

    MessageBox.Show(testing);
}
```

How can I pass testing into the WebBrowserDocumentCompleted function?  I'm not sure syntactically how to add it as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy by utilizing [closures](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)

```
public void TestStuff() 
{
    string testing = "test";
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(testing);
        };
    webBrowser2.Navigate("http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: Is it correct (formatting/readability wise) to have to DocumentCompleted above the Navigate call?

Comment: Okay.  One more question, the entire TestStuff() function is inside of a while loop, and so it's interrupting my Navigate() calls because it's asynchronous.  Do I put the entire while loop in a separate Thread or can you point me to a resource that might explain Threading/Background workers better?  Thanks.

Comment: Before this, I was using the answer on this question to help me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816553/while-loop-program-flow?rq=1

Comment: @Hubrid you are lucky since I answered a similar question today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273762/convert-html-page-to-a-image-using-webbrowser-in-asp-net-taking-too-much-time-to/18274404#18274404

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public TestStuff()  
   {
        string testing = "test";
        webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += ((WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
             evHandler(sender, testing);
        });
        webBrowser2.Navigate("http://google.com");

    }

   public void evHandler(Object sender, string testing)
   { 
         MessageBox.Show(testing);
   }
```

Comment: What is the difference from my answer other that using the old fashioned delegates? BTW: You should attach to `DocumentCompleted` before calling `Navigate`.

Comment: Also second argument should be of type `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` not `EventArgs`

Comment: And in C# method names start with Capital letter as convention.

Comment: @QtX Wow..I've never realy heard of that